# Why this method get executed without being called?

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, functional-testing, liipfunctionaltestbundle

According to [this documentation](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle#non-sqlite), I can write a `setUp()` function in my test class, like:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;
use Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class AccountControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        if (!isset($metadatas)) {
            $metadatas = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
        }
        $schemaTool = new SchemaTool($em);
        $schemaTool->dropDatabase();
        if (!empty($metadatas)) {
            $schemaTool->createSchema($metadatas);
        }
        $this->postFixtureSetup();

        $fixtures = array(
            'Acme\MyBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUserData',
        );
        $this->loadFixtures($fixtures);
    }
//...
}
```

But when I look for the `setUp()` method in the extended WebTestCase class, I don't find it. My understanding is that I can redefine a method from parent class in the child class. Parent class is:

https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle/blob/master/Test/WebTestCase.php

Please to explain to me why and when this method get executed? Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L2210 Went through all the classes. This is where method is originated from.

Comment: @E_p, thank you very much I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setUp()` is actually used by PHPUnit, which the Symfony testing framework extends.

Take a look at the PHPUnit documentation for more info: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html

Here's a link to the actual abstract class that Symfony is extending: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L2210

Comment: Furthermore, when you extend a class, you aren't limited to redefining existing methods. You can add entirely new methods, which can then be called by consuming code down the road.

Comment: Thank you for your informative feedback. I totally understand now. I forgot that PHPUnit comes as intgrated part of the Symfony2 standard edition. I thought it comes with the liipfunctionaltestbundle. Stupid mistake.